# L'Hospital's rule application

Tags: limits

I have to find out for which pair of functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ the following limit
$$\lim_{x\to x_{0}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
can be solved using L'Hospital's rule, and my options are:

1. $f(x)=x^2+x-6,\quad g(x)=x^2-3x+2,\quad x_{0}=2$
2. $f(x)=\sin(x)-x,\quad g(x)=e^x+e^{-x}-2,\quad x_{0}=0$
3. $f(x)=x^2\cdot\sin\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\quad g(x)=x,\quad x_{0}=0$
4. $f(x)=2x+7,\quad g(x)=4x+1,\quad x_{0}=3$
5. $f(x)=\ln(x),\quad g(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x},\quad x_{0}=0^{+}$

For me, the only item I can't use the rule is the 4th; but my problem is that, in the exercise I'm doing, there is no alternative that the items 1, 2, 3 and 5 are the correct answer.

So, my question is, in the 5th item, since the limit is
$$\frac{+\infty}{-\infty}$$
can I still use L'Hospital's rule here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'Hopital's rule can be applied to item 5.  For indeterminate forms, the signs don't matter.

L'Hopital's rule does not resolve item 3.  (Actually calculate the equivalent limit by L'Hopital's rule.)  Item 3 is resolved by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Why not? I mean, I got $0/0$ in item 3.

Comment: @mvfs314 : $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} g(x) = 1 \neq 0$.  And why do you think you can evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (- \cos(1/x) + 2x \sin(1/x))$?  That limit doesn't exist.